Why is TypeScript only returning one of the branches of extends?
Let's say we have this:
const func = (
  multiple: boolean
) => {
  type Value = typeof multiple extends true ? string[] : string

  if (multiple) {
    const foo: Value = ['string']
  } else {
    const bar: Value = 'string'
  }
}

This yields this TypeScript error for foo:
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

I was expecting Value to be string[] if multiple was true, what am I missing?

type Value = string: https://tsplay.dev/w82yPm

You are mixing types with the runtime

Generics can help you here

boolean extends true is...not. boolean doesn't extend (not subtype of) true. Therefore, Value is string.

Oh I see, thank you.

The conditional type typeof multiple extends true is always false. This is because boolean extends true and boolean extends false is always false too. Take a look to this:
type Value1 = typeof multiple extends true ? never : 'YES';
type Value2 = typeof multiple extends false ? never : 'YES';
type Value3 = boolean extends true ? never : 'YES';
type Value4 = boolean extends false ? never : 'YES';
type Check = 'YES' & Value1 & Value2 & Value3 & Value4; // YES

All Value1, Value2, Value3 and Value4 are type 'Yes'. This is proved because the union of all these types is only one (string literal) type 'Yes'.
You can fix it using the union type true | false instead of boolean.
type Value<T> = T extends true ? string[] : string;

const func = (
  multiple: true | false
) => {

  if (multiple) {
    const foo: Value<typeof multiple> = ['string']
  } else {
    const bar: Value<typeof multiple> = 'string'
  }
}


"You can fix it using the union type true | false instead of boolean." that's not the fix because boolean is defined as true | false. Playground Link What you've done is move where the type is checked, so it happens after narrowing it down to one of the two. The union is a red herring and it behaves exactly the same with your first set of tests: https://tsplay.dev/mA1bQm
